# Convert XML file using XSLT (combining multiple templates)

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I'm stuck at this problem for a while now. I have a sample XML File like this:

```
<Records>
 <Record><Id>1</Id><Name>table_id</Name><Attribute></Attribute><Value>1</Value></Record>
 <Record><Id>1</Id><Name>score</Name><Attribute></Attribute><Value>2.1</Value></Record>
 <Record><Id>1</Id><Name>custom4</Name><Attribute>name</Attribute><Value>Custom411</Value></Record>
 <Record><Id>1</Id><Name>custom4</Name><Attribute>name</Attribute><Value>Custom412</Value></Record>
 <Record><Id>2</Id><Name>table_id</Name><Attribute></Attribute><Value>2</Value></Record>
 <Record><Id>2</Id><Name>title</Name><Attribute></Attribute><Value>Title 2</Value></Record>
</Records>
```

I want to merge all the IDs and rows into another single XML file using XSLT in this format:

```
<RECORDS>
 <RECORD>
  <ITEM name="table_id" value="1"/>
  <ITEM name="score" value="2.1"/>
  <LIST name="custom4">
   <LIST_ITEM value="custom411"/>
   <LIST_ITEM value="custom412"/>
  </LIST>
 </RECORD>
 <RECORD>
  <ITEM name="table_id" value="2"/>
  <ITEM name="title" value="Title 2"/>
 </RECORD>
</RECORDS
```

Essentially value of `<table_id> = <Id>`. So for each `<Id>`, I need to create one `<RECORD>`. If multiple values of same `<Name>` exists for one `<Id>`, then I need to create a LIST_ITEM for that `<name>` otherwise create a normal ITEM.

So far I have been able to group the Records based on the `<Id>` using a template. But I am not able to use the output of this template in generating a final output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="output">
        <xsl:call-template name="groupById" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <OBJECTS>
    <xsl:for-each select="$output/Root/Records">
        <OBJECT>
            <xsl:for-each select="Id/Record">
                <ITEM>
                    <xsl:attribute name='name'>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name='value'>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </ITEM>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </OBJECT>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </OBJECTS>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="groupById">
    <Root>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="/Records/Record" group-by="Id">
      <Records>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="if(Id) then Id else 'no key'">   
            <!-- Copy attributes off the *first* Record element in the group -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/Id"/>
            <!-- Copy remaining children from *all* Record elements in the group -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Records>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone please guide me from here or suggest an alternate route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short but complete XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Records">
  <RECORDS>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="Id">
      <RECORD>
        <ITEM name="table_id" value="{current-grouping-key()}"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[not(Name = 'table_id')]" group-by="Name">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
              <LIST name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                  <LIST_ITEM value="{Value}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </LIST>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <ITEM name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
     </RECORD>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </RECORDS>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using Saxon 9, it transforms the input

```
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>table_id</Name>
    <Attribute></Attribute>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>score</Name>
    <Attribute></Attribute>
    <Value>2.1</Value>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>custom4</Name>
    <Attribute>name</Attribute>
    <Value>Custom411</Value>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>custom4</Name>
    <Attribute>name</Attribute>
    <Value>Custom412</Value>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>table_id</Name>
    <Attribute></Attribute>
    <Value>2</Value>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>title</Name>
    <Attribute></Attribute>
    <Value>Title 2</Value>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

into the following result:

```
<RECORDS>
   <RECORD>
      <ITEM name="table_id" value="1"/>
      <ITEM name="score" value="2.1"/>
      <LIST name="custom4">
         <LIST_ITEM value="Custom411"/>
         <LIST_ITEM value="Custom412"/>
      </LIST>
   </RECORD>
   <RECORD>
      <ITEM name="table_id" value="2"/>
      <ITEM name="title" value="Title 2"/>
   </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution is elegant. I was completely on the another track!